# Get Intent Before User uninstalled Application

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I know that there are intents for ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED and ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED.

I search for intent that I can know when the user wants to uninstall application, and I handle with the intent by allowing/disallowing his request to uninstall (assume I want to get the intent to other app, and the user wants to uninstall different application) There is relevant intent that I can listen to in order to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Short answer: it isn't possible on a non-rooted device.

Comment: And if this is rooted device, how can we do it? Thanks.